# How to extend rectangle box to one side while it fits to several nodes?

Tags: circuitikz, fit

How to extend dashed box below bottom wire? Upper box coordinate should remain at the same place:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt, varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage[americaninductors, europeanresistor]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{circuitikz}[every label/.style = {label distance=3mm,
                draw, inner sep=1.2mm,
                font=\bfseries}
    ]
    \ctikzset{wiper end arrow={Latex[width=4pt]}}


    \draw (0,-10) coordinate (p4)
    to[R, l_=$\underline{Z}_1$, name=Z1, mirror, -*] ++ (0, 4) coordinate (p1)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_2$, name=Z2, label distance=2px, -*] ++ (4, 0) coordinate (p2)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_3$, -*] ++ (0, -4) -| (p4)

    (p2) to[R=$\underline{Z}_5$, label distance=2px, -*] ++ (4, 0) coordinate (p30)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_6$, -*] ++ (0, -4) -- ++ (-4, 0)

    (p30) to[short, -o] ++ (2, 0)
    -- ++ (1,0) -- ++ (0, -1) coordinate (aux1)
    to[pR, l=$\underline{Z}_a{=}\underline{Z}_7$, name=R3, *-] ++ (0, -2) coordinate (aux2)
    (aux1)  -|  (R3.wiper)
    (aux2) -- ++ (0, -1) -- ++ (-1,0) to[short, o-] ++ (-2, 0)

    (p1) -- ++ (0,2) to[R=$\underline{Z}_4$, label distance=2px] ++ (8,0) -- (p30)

    (p1) to [short, -o] ++ (-2,0)
    (p4) to [short, *-o] ++ (-2,0);

   %Dashed box with label inside
    \node [draw, dashed, fit={(Z1) (Z2)}, inner xsep=0.5cm, inner ysep=0.8cm](dashed box){};
    \node [draw, thick, outer sep=1mm, above right] at (dashed box.south west) {A1};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Should be like this (label "A1" below bottom wire, resistor Z1 just for example):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion in this case is to change the last two lines this way:

1. Put the "A1" thing where you want:

```latex
%% draw the label before (remember the anchor rotate rigidly with the component!)
    \path (Z1.north west) ++(-.3,-.3) node[draw, thick, below left](lab A1) {A1};
```

2. After that, use a symmetric fit box (notice the usage of `Z2label`, which is the name of the label node that `circuitikz` creates automatically):

```latex
%Dashed box with label inside
    \node [draw, dashed, fit={(Z1) (Z2) (Z2label) (lab A1)}, inner sep=4pt](dashed box){};
```

The result is the following:

[image]

The complete code follows: I removed the `preview` and `varwidth` things from standalone (created overfull boxes) and removed the `every label` style, which affects only *native* Ti*k*Z labels, not the `circuitikz` ones.

```latex
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,]{standalone}
\usepackage[americaninductors, europeanresistor]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{wiper end arrow={Latex[width=4pt]}}

    \draw (0,-10) coordinate (p4)
    to[R, l_=$\underline{Z}_1$, name=Z1, mirror, -*] ++ (0, 4) coordinate (p1)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_2$, name=Z2, label distance=2px, -*] ++ (4, 0) coordinate (p2)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_3$, -*] ++ (0, -4) -| (p4)

    (p2) to[R=$\underline{Z}_5$, label distance=2px, -*] ++ (4, 0) coordinate (p30)
    to[R=$\underline{Z}_6$, -*] ++ (0, -4) -- ++ (-4, 0)

    (p30) to[short, -o] ++ (2, 0)
    -- ++ (1,0) -- ++ (0, -1) coordinate (aux1)
    to[pR, l=$\underline{Z}_a{=}\underline{Z}_7$, name=R3, *-] ++ (0, -2) coordinate (aux2)
    (aux1)  -|  (R3.wiper)
    (aux2) -- ++ (0, -1) -- ++ (-1,0) to[short, o-] ++ (-2, 0)

    (p1) -- ++ (0,2) to[R=$\underline{Z}_4$, label distance=2px] ++ (8,0) -- (p30)

    (p1) to [short, -o] ++ (-2,0)
    (p4) to [short, *-o] ++ (-2,0);

    %% draw the label before (remember the anchor rotate rigidly with the component!)
    \path (Z1.north west) ++(-.3,-.3) node[draw, thick, below left](lab A1) {A1};

   %Dashed box with label inside
    \node [draw, dashed, fit={(Z1) (Z2) (Z2label) (lab A1)}, inner sep=4pt](dashed box){};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

You can tune the rectangle by moving the block with A1: notice the command, which is

```
\path (Z1.north west) ++(-.3, -.3) node...
```

which says: get the position of the NW point of the resistor (which is rotated, and now it's the bottom left one), move *relatively* with respect to it (in this case, 0.3 to the left and 0.3 down) and position the "A1" label.

If you change the `++(-.3, -.3)` to `++(-1, -2)` you have:

[image]

Or position A1 relative to P4:

```latex
 \path (p4) ++(-.1,-.1) node[draw, thick, below left](lab A1) {A1};
```

[image]

Comment: But the result is the same.. "A1" label and rectangle bottom line should be below schematic.

Comment: I can do it by manually specifying additional coordinates, for example `... fit={(-1,-10.5) (Z1) (Z2)} ....`, but it's not convenient.. Somehow I need to get "Z1" y coordinate, add some value, and pass it to `fit` (left x coordinate remains the same).

Comment: But it's exactly what the code does! I tried to explain more --- you can put the A1 box wherever you want, and relative to Z1.

Comment: Yes, it works (but now hard to control vertical left and right rectangle lines..). I think would be better `... fit={(p4) (Z1) (Z2)} ....`, but add to `p4` coordinate some negative y value. Is it possible?

Comment: You can define a new coordinate: `\path (p4) ++(-1,-2) coordinate(p4shifted);` (there are other ways, but I find this quite intuitive. Then use `(p4shifted)`... Or position the node A1 relative to `p4`: `\path (p4) ++(-.3,-.3) node[draw, thick, below left](lab A1) {A1};`

Comment: Found this method: `... fit={($(Z1) +(0,-2.2)$) (Z1) (Z2)} ...`. Perhaps you can add this to your answer, would accept as solution.

Comment: I don't like that solution, sorry. It's mixing node and coordinates, and I find that fragile. If you prefer this, please add your own answer and accept that one ;-). No problem here. (I have added what I think it's the better solution).